# Unity3D how to get centered object of a ScrollView?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

So I have this ScrollView set up using ScrollRect that has a Viewport child which has an Image and a Mask (pretty basic ScrollView setup). Inside the scroll view I have 15 buttons. I want to know what button is at the center of my ScrollView, so I can disable all other buttons (to be unclickable). I tried it with `content.position.y` but it's different for every screen size.
Is there even anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One practical way I can see is if you have a new "Center" GameObject outside of the ScrollRect somewhere. And then compare the *global* position of that to each of the buttons.

So if the global y coordinate of the button is close (by some margin) to the global y coordinate of the "Center" Gameobject, you make the button interactable, otherwise not.

The nice thing here is that it's easily debuggable, because you can actually *see* the "Center" Gameobject. And because the "Center" Gameobject is also somewhere in the Canvas, you can set it up such that it adapts to the screensize however you like.

Comment: the problem here is that buttons inside the content always have the same y position, because when scrolling they don't actually change y position. Or is there a way to determine Y position regardless of the parent? ^^

Comment: Ah, it should be the _global_ [position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html). Also works for `RectTransform`. Or how are you reading the Y position of the buttons?

Comment: well, I just tried button.transform.position.y, but as I am now reading it should have something to do with rectTransform.TransformPoint?

Comment: huh. position should _really_ change though, it basically does TransformPoint for you. Can you check if `position.y` (__not__ `localPosition`) really doesn't change if the button moves on the screen? is it maybe the wrong button?